# Inequality with factorial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, factorial

Is it true that

For every $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb N$,

If $x\leq y$ and $ab\leq y$ and $a\leq x!$ and $b\leq (y-x)!$,

Then, $ab\leq a \sqrt {\frac{y!}{x!}}+b \sqrt {\frac{y!}{(y-x)!}}$?

My efforts so far:

- I made a Python code and assured that it is true for $a,b,x\leq 30$ and $y\leq 100$
- I managed to prove a very limited special case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM

$$a \sqrt {\frac{y!}{x!}}+b \sqrt {\frac{y!}{(y-x)!}}\ge 2\sqrt{ab}\sqrt[4]{y!\binom y x}\ge 2\sqrt{ab}\sqrt[4]{(ab)!}\ge ab$$

since for any $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $$n!\ge \frac1{16}n^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer! Could you please ellaborate on the reasoning of the first and the second inequalities? Also, which of the assumptions ($x\leq y$ and $ab\leq y$ and $a\leq x!$ and $b\leq (y-x)!$) are necessary for your proof?

Comment: @DudiFrid By $y\ge x$ we can assume $\binom y x \ge 1$ and by $y\ge ab$ we have that $\sqrt[4]{y!}\ge \sqrt[4]{(ab)!}$. The others seems not required.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the second inequality. Yet, I still don't understand how did you get the first inequality using AM-GM that says only that $\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdots x_n}$?

Comment: @DudiFrid I've just used $$\frac{A+B}2 \ge \sqrt{AB} \implies A+B \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$$

Comment: Great, thank you!!

Comment: @DudiFrid You are absolutely welcome! Bye